# Vim not running inside tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

When I try to open a file using `vim` inside `tmux` the whole window freezes. I have to kill the window with `C-a &`.

Here are my `~/.vimrc` settings:

```
:set autoindent
:set ts=4
:set number
:set shiftwidth=4
:set showmode
:filetype on
:filetype plugin on
:syntax enable
:set mouse=a
```

and `~/.tmux.conf`

```
# I like Ctrl-a as the default hotkey
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a

# Split window using | and -
unbind %
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v

# Set status bar
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-left ‘#[fg=green]#H’

# Highlight active window
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg red

# Makes window numbering start from 1, instead of 0
set -g base-index 1
```

I am facing the problem in RHEL. However the same config works fine in my Mac. I guess, things were working fine till my RHEL box got restarted and I tried to recover a file in from vi swap file.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[edit]: I tried `ssh` to other box inside `tmux` and running `vi` there. Works fine in remote box !

---

[added later]
Following the suggestion of @jasonwryan, I added the line `set -g default-terminal screen-256color` at the end of `tmux.conf`. That prevented programs like `less` from working.

`echo $TERM` inside tmux is "screen" and outside tmux is "xterm".

Searching for $TERM led me to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux, from where I added the line `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` as the first line of `tmux.conf`. This made the `$TERM` inside tmux to "screen-256color". But now when I start `vi` inside tmux, it displays the following error:

```
E558: Terminal entry not found in terminfo
'screen-256color' not known. Available builtin terminals are:
    builtin_riscos
    builtin_amiga
    builtin_beos-ansi
    builtin_ansi
    builtin_pcansi
    builtin_win32
    builtin_vt320
    builtin_vt52
    builtin_xterm
    builtin_iris-ansi
    builtin_debug
    builtin_dumb
defaulting to 'ansi'
```

---

Looks like I have solved the issue. Just added `set -g default-terminal xterm` as the first line of my ~/.tmux.conf and it worked !

Comment: It may not be related, but you should set the correct TERM in tmux with `set -g default-terminal screen-256color`

Comment: @jasonwryan, I tried adding that line at the end of my `.tmux.conf`, but it resulted in programs like `less` not working properly

Comment: Can you update your question with your $TERM in and outside tmux?

Comment: @jasonwryan, I am a tmux newbie. Please explain what you are suggesting in more detail.

Comment: Outside of tmux, execute 'echo $TERM'. Inside of a tmux session, execute 'echo $TERM'.

Comment: Does vim work outside of tmux, are you sure it's not related to the file recovery issue?

Comment: @EightBitTony: Yes vim works outside of tmux. I have tried it on the same files.

Comment: @jasonwryan, @uther :: `echo $TERM` outside tmux is "xterm"; inside tmux it becomes "screen". But what does this mean?

Comment: On the remote machine (where tmux/vim works) run `infocmp screen-256color` and `infocmp screen`- if neither error out, you can copy one of those terminfo to your local machine.

Comment: @jasonwryan, I ran `infocmp screen-256color` and got
"infocmp: couldn't open terminfo file /usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color"

For `infocmp screen` I got a huge output beginning with:

#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/s/screen
screen|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal, ...

I don't know what you mean by "copy one of those terminfo to your local machine"

Comment: If you defininitely don't have a screen terminfo on your local box (where tmux/vim _doesn't_ work), on the remote box, do `infocmp screen > screeninfo`, scp that to your local box and install it with `sudo tic screeninfo`.

Comment: `infocomp screen` runs in both my local box where tmux+vi does not work and also in the remote machine. The outputs are here: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=b9TzzM2Z ; do I still need to do the steps you mentioned?

Comment: If you diff the files, they are slightly different: I'd copy the working one across and see if it fixes your issue. Other than that, I'm stumped...

Comment: I did that and subsequently checked using `infocmp screen` in both boxes to ensure they were same. But the problem still persists. I tried closing all open terminals and all tmux sessions and tried again. Still persists.

Comment: SOLVED !! ... added the solution at the end of original question. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: You should only set your tmux TERM to a screen derivative: see [the FAQ](http://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/trunk/FAQ): it will cause you issues down the track otherwise...

Comment: You should write your own answer and post it, with that in it, and then accept it (it's perfectly acceptable to do so).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the line

```
set -g default-terminal xterm
```

as the first line of my ~/.tmux.conf and it worked fine.

However as @jasonwryan has pointed out, the [TMUX FAQ](http://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/trunk/FAQ) clearly states that:

> Most display problems are due to incorrect TERM! Before
>   reporting problems make SURE that TERM settings are correct inside and
>   outside tmux.
>
> Inside tmux TERM must be "screen" or similar (such as
>   "screen-256color"). Outside, it must match your terminal ...

I only post this answer as it actually solved my problem. please feel free to add your alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem on an old CentOS box I had to work on. For me setting TERM in tmux to xterm caused other strange issues to pop up. However, I was able to fix it by commenting out `set mouse=a` in my .vimrc c.f. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2005-04/msg00039.html

Apparently adding `set ttymouse=xterm2` to your .vimrc may also do the trick.

For anyone else running into similar issues I recommend temporarily moving your .vimrc to see if something in there is the cause.